# Removing identifying information from .pdf files for peer review

Tags: pdftex

I am using the latest version of TeXShop for Mac with default settings.

Is there any chance that I could be identified from the .pdfs produced by this software, for instance through the .pdf metadata? Are there any steps I must take to ensure this does not happen? (Of course, I do not include any identifying information in the text of the document itself.)

I ask because my ability to effectively peer review for academic journals depends on my ability to produce anonymous reports, and I would like to be able to do this without worry using LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it should not be a problem. However you need to be aware of potential Issues. I have often recovered data that was not supposed to be there. On one occasion tracing a number of users that had sequentially edited a document in order to inform them they had a virus. Additionally I have had to explain to users how they may recover previous edits from a pdf "history".

There was a study done that showed the peer review process could give personal details away. I used it in an answer somewhere. If I remember correctly the main cause is repeated edits not replacing full contents simply marking parts as deleted hence some people have been caught out by poor redaction.

Much of this is down to the editing processes used. Thus with the correct settings  producing a simple pdf without metadata. A first run (or few pass) compilation from fresh TeX should not include too much personal detail.

The most common giveaway is the imbedded location of the build so assuming you build your files in a folder such as

c:\users\user179408\my secret latex fetish\documents

your  file may contain such an imbedded giveaway here is a stream by **alex** who used powerpoint

pdf:Producer='Acrobat Distiller 5.0.5 (Windows)' pdf:Author='alex' pdf:Creator='PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2' pdf:Title='Microsoft PowerPoint - 08_Image Filtering_09.ppt'/>
http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/' xmlns:xap='http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/' xap:CreateDate='2009-03-08T04:54:19Z' xap:ModifyDate='2009-03-08T04:54:19Z' xap:Author='alex' xap:MetadataDate='2009-03-08T04:54:19Z'>

Here is a simple pdf from MiKTeX which gives little extra info other than the versions. Thus it is relatively clean.

[image]

https://zdoc.site/security-and-privacy-issues-in-the-portable-document-format-.html
An extract from above also pointed out that with some recent pdfs you can track readership.

[Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics 
Protecting Referee Personal Information](https://www.siam.org/Publications/Journals/Related/Journal-Policies/Detail/protecting-referee-personal-information)

[Another describing bad redaction from the PDFa org](https://www.pdfa.org/member-news/is-the-information-you-just-redacted-really-gone/)

---

In summary with a basic TeX compilation there should be little to worry about
It is usually subsequent post processing or including PDFa metadata that can compromise privacy.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Do you know if pdflatex embeds the build location by default? How might I detect whether this information is present in a .pdf file?